# How to show tooltip while not focusing at pyqt5 python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to show tooltip while not focusing.

I made the code by referring to this [PyQt Window Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12280815/pyqt-window-focus)

But, it works after click window just one. Works fine, but window always blink at taskbar.

And I think this method is inefficient.

I think it's as if os are not resting while waiting for task to come, but checking every moment for task to come.

This is a simple window window, so it won't use up the cpu much, but I want to code it more efficiently.

Is there any way to improve this?

Or this method right because focusoutEvent excuted only one? ( Cpu resource 0% )

If right, how can I remove blink at taskbar?

I check reference [focusPolicy-prop](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusPolicy-prop)

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(2)
        btn = QPushButton("Test")
        btn.setToolTip("This tooltip")
        vbox.addWidget(btn)
        vbox.addStretch(1)

        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()

    def focusOutEvent(self, event):
        self.setFocus(True)
        self.activateWindow()
        self.raise_()
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You are using Windows, I suppose, right?

Comment: @musicamante yes

Comment: What is the need of showing a tooltip when refocusing? Where should it appear?

Comment: @musicamante There's button name is number, and tooltip show image. Just appear like normal tooltip( like post code )

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not clear. Why do you need to show the tooltip after giving back focus to the window? And where should the tooltip appear?

Comment: @musicamante I just use image tooltip what you answer before. If there's no focus at window, tooltip not showing up. I just want to delete effort to click window for getting tooltip by focusing

Comment: @musicamante **window** not window10, program window

Comment: So you want to be able to show tooltips even if the window does not have focus?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, code written above work what i expected. But I wonder this code right in an efficient way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): trying to find a solution (usually unorthodox and overly complicated) for a problem that is originated elsewhere.

What you want to do is to show tooltips even if the window is not focused, not to restore the focus of the window; to achieve this you **must not** reactivate the window when it loses focus (which not only is *WRONG*, but is both a wrong way and reason for doing so).

You just have to set the `WA_AlwaysShowToolTips` [widget attribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) on the top level window (and remove the unnecessary `focusOutEvent` override, obviously).

```
class MyApp(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
        self.initUI()
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysShowToolTips, True)
```

Note that the attribute must be set on a widget that is a *top level window*, so, unless you're using a QMainWindow or you are absolutely sure that the QWidget will always be a window, it's usually better to do this instead:

```
    self.window().setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysShowToolTips, True)
```

Besides that, the blinking is normal on windows, and has nothing to do with CPU usage:

> [activateWindow()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow):
>   [...] On Windows, if you are calling this when the application is not currently the active one then it will not make it the active window. **It will change the color of the taskbar entry to indicate that the window has changed in some way.** This is because Microsoft does not allow an application to interrupt what the user is currently doing in another application.

Comment: How did you find `WA_AlwaysShowToolTips`? I search with **tooltip, focus, window** at google but nothing comes out... If there's any method to find func at reference, I want to learn.

Comment: Read the *widget attribute* link in the answer, I don't put them there just for fun... ;)

Comment: I searched like [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/search-results.html?q=tooltip%20while%20not%20focusing) and it didn't come out for 5 hours, so I was wondering if there's a way to look up reference. Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: I never use the qt site search, especially for "semantic" searches like yours (although "smart", current search algorithms are still based on literal words, not their meaning, especially when limited to a single website). The only solution is to patiently study the documentation and become more accustomed with the classes and their functions (the mandatory classes are without any doubt QObject and QWidget, but reading all QtCore.Qt enum/flags is also a good thing). It takes time, but Qt is a *big*, complex and comprehensive framework, you can't expect to use it just with "random" searches.

Comment: Consider this: it took you 5 hours to find *nothing*. In the same amount of time, you could have read (at least) both QWidget and QtCore.Qt pages completely, you'd have probably found what you were looking for in half of that time, while still learning a lot of other things you didn't know about... :)

Comment: @4rigener see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum